# Upgrade RAM Memory

Tags: memory, lenovo-laptop, memory-limit, memory-usage

I have a Lenovo G510 laptop. I'm an android developer, and most of the time I'm working with the Android Studio program.

As some of you know, android studio takes about 1 GB from my RAM and the Java program takes another 200 MB, while the G510 has 4 GB RAM Memory.

When I'm working with android studio, the Program Manager normally says that I'm using about 95%-99% of my RAM Memory, even when there is no other programs on the background.

I have 2 questions about it:

1. How many of my RAM Memory is for my own usage? Because some of the websites says 1.5 GB and the others says 2.5 GB, and there are a few websites that says that I can use the whole 4 GB. 

2. How many RAM can I add to my laptop? Is there a limit on how much RAM Memory I can add to my Lenovo G510 laptop?

Comment: As long as you are not getting low memory messages you are fine. You might edit your question to include the OS you have installed.

Comment: Whatever you’re using to check memory usage also tells you the total usable amount of memory.

Comment: Are you running a 64-bit OS?

Comment: @grawity nope. I'm running Windows 10

Comment: ...I didn't know a 32-bit Windows 10 even exists...

Comment: @grawity Why not? Before the upgrade I had Windows 7 32 bit and after the upgrade, I have Windows 10 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question really doesn't make sense. The operating system manages all of memory and will try to assign that memory in such a way as to provide as much performance as possible. Having a decent size page file helps the OS to make efficient use of memory even when the page file isn't used (don't ask, it's complicated).

One important thing to understand is that high memory use doesn't mean low memory availability. Most of the memory that's in use is also available.

The G510 can physically accommodate 16GB but Lenovo seems to say that it only supports 8GB. Several sites that sell add on memory offer 16GB kits for it, so it's near certain that 16GB works.